# How Can I set Actionbar, Title and BackButton in PreferenceActivity like AppCompactActivity...?

Tags: android-actionbar, preferenceactivity

this is my Setting class:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);
}
```

Please help me guys how can set ACTIONBAR, TITLE and BACLBUTTON like AppcompactActivity

This is my main Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    boolean first =settings.getBoolean("first",false);
    String rings=settings.getString("ringtone","Default Rings");
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
      Intent intent= new Intent(MainActivity.this,SettingClass.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```